# How to update the value of version key in package.json

Tags: git, git-flow

I use git flow to manage my work flow on git. I use yarn but I can't seem to find any answer on how to update the version in my `package.json`

I guess there must be some way to bump up the version when I merge/create a release branch.
I name my release branches as `release/v3.23.3` but since that's not a rule so apparently git doesn't care. Please tell me a good way to bump up the release version.

Answer (score 1):

[Dafna Rosenblum recommends](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-i-established-a-good-release-process-in-javascript-b93e57e247e1/):

npm-version

> After creating the release branch, you should running `./bump-version.sh`.
> This is a fictional script that updates the version number of the project.
>
> As I mentioned, the Git Flow article is from January 2010. This is also the month [NPM was first released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) (coincidence??), and I prefer using [`npm-version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version.html) like below:
>
> ```
> npm version patch
> ```
>
> The output will be the new version number.
> A commit will be added to the branch with the new version updated in the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.
>
> An alternative to `npm-version` is the popular tool [`release-it`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/release-it), that can bump version, create tags and releases, and more.